# Iterating through an STL map with an iterator by different threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, stl, synchronization

I have an STL map that will be accessed by two threads.
Neither of them inserts nor removes elements: they just read.

If it were just a simple array, I am sure that this would never cause trouble.
However, the STL map is a complicated data structure whose implementation is unknown to me.
Will this cause a data race?

Comment: Ah ha, found what I was looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9042626/1171191

Comment: @BoBTFish, so my requirement is guaranteed...thanks

Answer (score 2):

Standard C++ containers (as of 2011) allow safe access by multiple concurrent readers (i.e. via `const` member functions).

That is, you are ok (assuming the `const` member functions on the types you are using with the container follow the same rules: bitwise-`const` except on objects that are protected from access by other threads).

If you are using an old implementation you may in theory have problems, but I doubt it.

Here's an entire chunk of the Library introduction section of The Standard ([`N3337`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf)). I don't think any one of these paragraphs alone is enough to answer your question, so you get the whole lot!

> 17.6.5.9 Data race avoidance **[res.on.data.races]**
>
> 1 This section specifies requirements that implementations shall meet to prevent data
>   races (1.10). Every standard library function shall meet each
>   requirement unless otherwise specified. Implementations may prevent
>   data races in cases other than those specified below.
>
> 2 A C++ standard
>   library function shall not directly or indirectly access objects
>   (1.10) accessible by threads other than the current thread unless the
>   objects are accessed directly or indirectly via the function’s
>   arguments, including this.
>
> 3 A C++ standard library function shall not
>   directly or indirectly modify objects (1.10) accessible by threads
>   other than the current thread unless the objects are accessed directly
>   or indirectly via the function’s non-const arguments, including this.
>
> 4 [ Note: This means, for example, that implementations can’t use a
>   static object for internal purposes without synchronization because it
>   could cause a data race even in programs that do not explicitly share
>   objects between threads. —end note ]
>
> 5 A C++ standard library function
>   shall not access objects indirectly accessible via its arguments or
>   via elements of its container arguments except by invoking functions
>   required by its specification on those container elements.
>
> 6
>   Operations on iterators obtained by calling a standard library
>   container or string member function may access the underlying
>   container, but shall not modify it. [ Note: In particular, container
>   operations that invalidate iterators conflict with operations on
>   iterators associated with that container. —end note ]
>
> 7
>   Implementations may share their own internal objects between threads
>   if the objects are not visible to users and are protected against data
>   races.
>
> 8 Unless otherwise specified, C++ standard library functions
>   shall perform all operations solely within the current thread if those
>   operations have effects that are visible (1.10) to users.
>
> 9 [ Note: This allows implementations to parallelize operations if there are no visible side effects. —end note ]

Comment: As long as only const members are used, and the values adhere to the same (const members cannot alter anything _at the bit level_; only exemption: thread primitives like `std::mutex`)

Comment: According to http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/begin
there are different versions of begin:
(1) iterator begin()
(2) const_iterator begin() const:
My question is "how do I know which one will be used"?

Comment: @takwing Iff you have a `const` object, you get the `const` version. However, if you specifically know you want `const_iterator`s and don't care about the `const`ness of the `map` in your context use the [`cbegin`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/begin) and [`cend`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/end) member functions.

Comment: @BoBTFish, by const object, does it mean that the values in the <key,value> entries are of a const type?

Comment: @takwing I mean if the `map` itself is `const`, then `myMap.begin()` will return a `const_iterator`. The `map` may be `const` for various reasons, including: 1) it was declared that way: `const std::map<int, int> myMap;` (of limited use). 2) it is accessed as a member of a `const` class instance: `const MyClass myInstance; myInstance.mapMember_.begin();`. 3) you access a member of some class inside a `const` member function (this is basically 2): `void myClass::foo() const { mapMember_.begin(); }`.